# ¿Cómo puedo identificar y eliminar 'data contains non-finite values'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scipy, statsmodels

Con el siguiente script intento calcular, dentro de una clase, el VaR Histórico y el Teórico obtenidos a través de la distribución normal,

```
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
from scipy.stats import norm

def get_quotes(ticker, start_day, end_day):
    yfObj = yf.Ticker(ticker)
    name = yfObj.info['shortName']
    df = yf.download(ticker, start= start_day, end = end_day)
    df.rename(columns={'Adj Close': name }, inplace=True)
    data = df.drop(['Close','High', 'Low', 'Open', 'Volume'], axis=1 )
    return data, name

ticker_val = 'SPY'
start_day = "1993-1-1"
end_day = "2019-11-1"

# Import Market quotes
df_aux, name =  get_quotes(ticker_val, start_day, end_day)
df_aux['returns'] = df_aux[name].pct_change()
df_aux.dropna( ) 

class CalculadorIndicadoresRiesgo:
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df 

    # VaR Teórico obtenido a través de la distribución normal al 95% y 99% de confianza.
    def theoretical_var (self) :
        print ('\nAdjusted parameters of the normal distribution used by SNS')
        (mu, sigma) = stats.norm.fit(df_aux[name])
        print (f"\t>VaR Gaussian model NC-95% :  {norm.ppf(0.05, mu, sigma)*100:.2f}%") 
        print (f"\t>VaR Gaussian model NC-99% :  {norm.ppf(0.01, mu, sigma)*100:.2f}%")
        print (f"\t>VaR Gaussian model NC-99.7% :  {norm.ppf(0.003, mu, sigma)*100:.2f}%")
       
    # VaR histórico al 95% y 99% de confianza.
    def historical_var (self) :
        print ('\nVaR Thistórico al 95% y 99% de confianza.')
        (mu, sigma) = stats.norm.fit(df_aux['returns'])
        print (f"\t> VaR Gaussian model NC-95% :  {np.percentile(self.df_aux['returns']*100, 5):.2f}%") 
        print (f"\t> VaR Gaussian model NC-95% :  {np.percentile(self.df_aux['returns']*100, 1):.2f}%") 
        print (f"\t> VaR Gaussian model NC-95% :  {np.percentile(self.df_aux['returns']*100, .3):.2f}%") 
        print (80*'=')          
        
indicadores_riesgo = CalculadorIndicadoresRiesgo( df_aux)
indicadores_riesgo.theoretical_var()
indicadores_riesgo.historical_var ()
```

Me devuelve:

```
Adjusted parameters of the normal distribution used by SNS
    >VaR Gaussian model NC-95% :  229.39%
    >VaR Gaussian model NC-99% :  -4164.49%
    >VaR Gaussian model NC-99.7% :  -6881.64%

VaR Thistórico al 95% y 99% de confianza.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_9457/4260036454.py in <module>
     22 indicadores_riesgo = CalculadorIndicadoresRiesgo( df_aux)
     23 indicadores_riesgo.theoretical_var()
---> 24 indicadores_riesgo.historical_var ()

/tmp/ipykernel_9457/4260036454.py in historical_var(self)
     14     def historical_var (self) :
     15         print ('\nVaR Thistórico al 95% y 99% de confianza.')
---> 16         (mu, sigma) = stats.norm.fit(df_aux['returns'])
     17         print (f"\t> VaR Gaussian model NC-95% :  {np.percentile(self.df_aux['returns']*100, 5):.2f}%")
     18         print (f"\t> VaR Gaussian model NC-95% :  {np.percentile(self.df_aux['returns']*100, 1):.2f}%")

~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/stats/_continuous_distns.py in wrapper(self, *args, **kwds)
     60             return super(type(self), self).fit(*args, **kwds)
     61         else:
---> 62             return fun(self, *args, **kwds)
     63     return wrapper
     64 

~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/stats/_continuous_distns.py in fit(self, data, **kwds)
    361 
    362         if not np.isfinite(data).all():
--> 363             raise RuntimeError("The data contains non-finite values.")
    364 
    365         if floc is None:

RuntimeError: The data contains non-finite values.
```

Gracias de antemano por vuestra ayuda.

He comprobado que el error se devuelve en la sentencia

```
(mu, sigma) = stats.norm.fit(df['returns'])    
mu, sigma
```

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_7998/4268868510.py in 
----> 1 (mu, sigma) = stats.norm.fit(df['returns'])
2
3 mu, sigma

```
~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/stats/_continuous_distns.py in wrapper(self, *args, **kwds)
     60             return super(type(self), self).fit(*args, **kwds)
     61         else:
---> 62             return fun(self, *args, **kwds)
     63     return wrapper
     64 

~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/stats/_continuous_distns.py in fit(self, data, **kwds)
    361 
    362         if not np.isfinite(data).all():
--> 363             raise RuntimeError("The data contains non-finite values.")
    364 
    365         if floc is None:

RuntimeError: The data contains non-finite values.
```

¿Podría ser debido a que la columna 'returns' tiene valores muy pequeños?
[![Columna returns][1]][1]

He comprobado   si en la columna hay non-finete values, haciendo

~np.isfinite(df['returns'])

Me devuelve

[![ivalores non finite][2]][2]
valores non-finite
Es evidente que en la primera línea tengo un nan. Elimino esta línea con el métdo df.dropna() y el problema se resuelve,
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VThKG.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLhNI.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Hay unos pequeños errores en tu código y por eso devuelve error en la línea `(mu, sigma) = stats.norm.fit(df_aux['returns'])`

El problema es que el método `norm.fit()` no permite `NaN`, según la [documentación](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.fit), dice que si el arreglo contiene `NaN` o valores infinitos entonces devolverá un `RuntimeError`

Ahora, el problema por el que tienes `NaN` en tu `dataframe` es porque al hacer `df_aux.dropna( )` se te olvidó sobreescribir el `dataframe` o crear uno nuevo, por lo que debes hacer

```
df_aux = df_aux.dropna( )
```

Tienes otro error que aún no te ha aparecido porque el código se interrumpe al encontrar el `RuntimeError` del `norm.fit()`, en tu clase `class CalculadorIndicadoresRiesgo:` en el `__init__()` estas definiendo una variable `self.df`, pero en el método `def historical_var (self) :` al final quieres imprimir algo que utiliza `self.df_aux`. El error te va a decir que `self.df_aux` no existe, esto es porque la llamaste `self.df` en el `__init__()`

```
print (f"\t> VaR Gaussian model NC-95% :  {np.percentile(self.df_aux['returns']*100, 5):.2f}%")
```

Corrigiendo los errores antes mencionados y aplicándolos a tu código ya funciona de forma correcta

```
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
from scipy.stats import norm

def get_quotes(ticker, start_day, end_day):
    yfObj = yf.Ticker(ticker)
    name = yfObj.info['shortName']
    df = yf.download(ticker, start= start_day, end = end_day)
    df.rename(columns={'Adj Close': name }, inplace=True)
    data = df.drop(['Close','High', 'Low', 'Open', 'Volume'], axis=1 )
    return data, name

ticker_val = 'SPY'
start_day = "1993-1-1"
end_day = "2019-11-1"

# Import Market quotes
df_aux, name =  get_quotes(ticker_val, start_day, end_day)
df_aux['returns'] = df_aux[name].pct_change()
df_aux = df_aux.dropna( )        #<--- Despues de eliminar los NaN debes asignar el resultado otra vez a tu dataframe

class CalculadorIndicadoresRiesgo:
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df 

    # VaR Teórico obtenido a través de la distribución normal al 95% y 99% de confianza.
    def theoretical_var (self) :
        print ('\nAdjusted parameters of the normal distribution used by SNS')
        (mu, sigma) = stats.norm.fit(df_aux[name])
        print (f"\t>VaR Gaussian model NC-95% :  {norm.ppf(0.05, mu, sigma)*100:.2f}%") 
        print (f"\t>VaR Gaussian model NC-99% :  {norm.ppf(0.01, mu, sigma)*100:.2f}%")
        print (f"\t>VaR Gaussian model NC-99.7% :  {norm.ppf(0.003, mu, sigma)*100:.2f}%")
       
    # VaR histórico al 95% y 99% de confianza.
    def historical_var (self) :
        print ('\nVaR Thistórico al 95% y 99% de confianza.')
        (mu, sigma) = stats.norm.fit(df_aux['returns'])
        print (f"\t> VaR Gaussian model NC-95% :  {np.percentile(self.df['returns']*100, 5):.2f}%")    # <---- self no tiene un elemento df_aux, se llama df según lo que hiciste en __init__
        print (f"\t> VaR Gaussian model NC-95% :  {np.percentile(self.df['returns']*100, 1):.2f}%")    # <---- self no tiene un elemento df_aux, se llama df según lo que hiciste en __init__
        print (f"\t> VaR Gaussian model NC-95% :  {np.percentile(self.df['returns']*100, .3):.2f}%")   # <---- self no tiene un elemento df_aux, se llama df según lo que hiciste en __init__
        print (80*'=')          
        
indicadores_riesgo = CalculadorIndicadoresRiesgo( df_aux)
indicadores_riesgo.theoretical_var()
indicadores_riesgo.historical_var ()
```